# Drop table when uninstalling plugin with confirm message in WordPress (are you sure want to delete data)?

Tags: wordpress

How can I add a confirm popup to ask whether to delete database table or not when a plugin is being uninstalled?

I don't know how to go about this. Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the code which you have already tried to solve the problem with.